# Why do the majority of SSL cipher suite used CBC?

Tags: block-cipher, tls, cbc, modes-of-operation, gcm

I am looking at a wireshark capture of the cipher suites sent by my browser to the server during an SSL handshake; however, almost 90% of them use CBC, with 2 or 3 having GCM.

Why is CBC most used? Is there a specific property that makes CBC preferred by web communications?

Also literature suggests that the non-feedback modes (e.g., counter mode) perform better in practice; however GCM shows up in only a few cipher suites.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically, CBC was for long the dominant block cipher mode, but in recent years there's been a slow but firm move away from it, based on two trends:

1. The move toward **authenticated encryption** as the "go-to" ciphers for practical applications;
2. A reevaluation of the merits of CTR-based modes over CBC, driven by a variety of factors like:

   - The proliferation of attacks against CBC-based ciphersuites;
   - The simplicity and performance of CTR.

So you see a lot of CBC because it was the king for a long time, and it's only going away slowly.  [This blog entry by Cloudfare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/padding-oracles-and-the-decline-of-cbc-mode-ciphersuites/) has graphs of the SSL cipher suites they're seeing and shows AES-GCM gradually gaining over AES-CBC.

Two references I've found useful:

- [Phillip Rogaway, "Evaluation of Some Blockcipher
  Modes of Operation"](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/modes.pdf)
- [Chris J. Mitchell, "Error Oracle Attacks on CBC Mode:
  Is There a Future for CBC Mode Encryption?"](https://repository.royalholloway.ac.uk/file/7357acd9-e76b-2cea-a9b3-ebc4da49d5cc/9/eoaocm2.pdf)

Comment: Backwards compatibility just rules the world ...

Comment: Note that CCM, EAX and of course GCM use CTR mode underneath.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: to be clear, that's what I meant when I said "CTR-**based**" instead of just "CTR."

Comment: @LuisCasillas Well, that's nice *once you know* that many authenticated ciphers are based on CTR, but otherwise that's a pretty impossible connection to make. I just mentioned it because I thought that statement needed an example or two. And, in that sense, the note wasn't directed to you.